# How to import a JSON on Folium for Neighborhoods

Tags: python, json, geolocation, geojson, folium

I am trying to have a Map of Chicago with the Districts on it. I got a json file from this link
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/boundaries-neighborhoods/resource/2011ff13-c18e-44ea-9147-1bbcc7b1f122
and I would like to use it to have the boundaries of the different district.

The problem is that I tried for hours to do so, but I am kinda a newcomer on folium.

I know that my json contains 'meta' and 'data', but when I use the following code

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="ch_explore")
location = geolocator.geocode("Chicago,IL")
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))

lat=location.latitude
lng=location.longitude

CHI_N_path =os.path.join('c:' + os.sep, 'Users', 'Valentin','Desktop','Perso','RessourceCours','Chicago_N.json')
folium.GeoJson(data=(open(CHI_N_path, "r").read()),name='geojson',).add_to(CHI_map)
```

There are no addition to the map, and I do not have anymore information.

Does someone have an idea on why it doesn't display ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I glanced at your file. Looks like it's a JSON file that has geometry but not in a geojson format that folium likes.  Perhaps you could use something like this instead https://github.com/blackmad/neighborhoods/blob/master/chicago.geojson

Comment: Thank you for the information. So I tried to use the wrong dataset. I will try to use the file you linked instead :) By the way, how could I recognize the right type of json data that I need to use for folium ? That would help me to not do the same mistake again